# box shadow and other color effects are not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a pop up signup form with bootstrap modal class. And I used some jQuery validation engine to validate the form. And there I added a box shadow and changed the background color and color. This is working well on Chrome and Internet Explorer but it's not working on Firefox.

Here is my form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signupForm" data-backdrop="false" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content Popmodal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close Popclose" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="">
                    <span>&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title Poptit">Sign Up</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body Popbody">
                <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="registration.php" id="reg-form">
                    <div class="form-group"><br>
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">User Name :</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="A name that you like to use" class="form-control input-sm popname validate[required]" name="uname" id="uname" data-errormessage-value-missing="Username is required !" data-prompt-position="bottomLeft:5,4"><br>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Email :</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Your email address" class="form-control input-sm popname validate[required,custom[email]]" name="mail" id="mail" data-errormessage-value-missing="Email is required !"  data-errormessage-custom-error="Invalid email address !" data-prompt-position="bottomLeft:5,4"><br>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Password :</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Password" class="form-control input-sm popname validate[required]" name="pass" id="pass" data-errormessage-value-missing="Password is required !"  data-prompt-position="bottomLeft:5,4"><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">Confirm Password :</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="password" maxlength="15" placeholder="Confirm password" class="form-control input-sm popname validate[required,equals[pass]]" name="cpass" id="cpass" data-errormessage-value-missing="Confirm password is required !" data-errormessage-pattern-mismatch="Password fields do not match !" data-prompt-position="bottomLeft:5,4"><br>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-8">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success sign" value="submit" name="signup">Sign Up</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.formError .formErrorContent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #222;
    position:relative;
    color:#EE330E;
    min-width: 120px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #EE330E;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(238, 51, 14, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(238, 51, 14, 0.6);
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -o-border-radius: 6px;    
}
```

jQuery-Validation-Engine - [link](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)

Comment: [box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) has been supported unprefixed in all browsers for years. You should not be using any prefixes for it.

Answer (score 3):

You were missing the non vendor prefix for the box shadow.

I would actually recommend removing vendor prefixes for both box shadow and border radius as they are no longer an experimental feature.

See: http://shouldiprefix.com/#box-shadow

However I have updated your code with the missing line:

```
#signupForm .formError .formErrorContent {
  width: 100%;
  background: #222;
  position:relative;
  color:#EE330E;
  min-width: 120px;
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid #EE330E;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(238, 51, 14, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(238, 51, 14, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(238, 51, 14, 0.6);
  padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -o-border-radius: 6px;    
}
```

Edit -----

Just in case the validation isn't working at all in Firefox... ensure the validation plugin is applying the bind to the element after the modal is fired, for example:

```
$('#signupForm').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $("#reg-form").validationEngine();
}
```

Comment: Vendor specific code for `box-shadow` are not needed in the latest browsers anymore. Good catch!

Comment: @David Battersby I tried your solution but still not working. Thanks for the tip by the way.

Comment: @Kasun Is the issue to do with the box-shadow or something more?

Comment: @DavidBattersby Not only with the box shadow, background color,font color and border color also not working

Comment: @Kasun Is the validation working at all in Firefox? I've edited the CSS to prepend an ID to add more value to the rules. I've also added an example of how the validation plugin should be applied to the element in case it's a JS issue.